# How do you import entries from a CSV

Tags: import, export, csv

I'm fairly new to Craft CMS, and investigating how to handle exports and imports.

I noticed that on the Entries listing there's a nice big export CSV button - perfect, exactly what I need.

But I cannot see where to import this again.

For context, I'm using a multi site setup and want to be able to quickly clone one of my sites to a new one at any time. This doesn't seem to be available functionality, but the existence of the export button for entries makes me assume there must be import functionality somewhere?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is Feed me plugin for import..

But that export will not help you much. perhaps for some simpler fields..

You will need to write your own export..

Try DNA reports plugin